# Ideal of C* algebras

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $I$ be an ideal of algebra $A$.

prove that if $$a\in A$$  $$c\in I$$ and $$0 \leq {a^*a} \leq c $$

then $a\in I$.

I would like to use this lemma:

Let $x\in A$ and $a\in A_+ $ such that $x^* x \leq a$, then for all $0<\alpha<0.5$ there is a $b\in \overline{Aa}\subset A$ such tha $x=ba^{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $c \in A_+$. By your lemma, there exists a $b \in \overline{Ac}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1/2)$ such that
$$
a = bc^{\alpha}
$$
The key here, then, is to note that any closed ideal containing $c$ must also contain $c^\alpha$.

Comment: Can I say that $\overline {Ac}$ is an ideal?

Comment: I'm actually not sure.